# Ffmpeg: how to resize video to 1080x607

Tags: ffmpeg

i need to resize a video from 1920x1080 to 1080x607 for Instagram purpose.
I've tried

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=1080:607 output.mp4
```

but

````
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height ```
    
[aac @ 0x556816370380] Qavg: 128.675
[aac @ 0x556816370380] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
````

Comment: Maybe someting is wrong with the aspect ratio try scale=1080:-1 that would keep the relative aspect ratio but may not result in a hight of 607

Comment: Are you sure the original resolution is  1920x1080  maybe it is worth to double check...

Comment: IIRC, h264 is the default mp4 codec and it requires height and width to be even numbers. Try `scale=1080:608` or if you're trying to keep the aspect ratio do `scale=1080:-2`

Comment: Referring kesh' comment, I am getting an informative error message `height not divisible by 2 (1080x607)`. Simple solution is using `yuv444p` pixel format: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=1080:607 -pix_fmt yuv444p output.mp4`.